# Sync object scale from client to client

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

My friend and I have created a 2D shooter and now we're implementing multiplayer features, but we're having difficulties when the player model switches his facing direction (the player is facing in the direction of the mouse pointer). When we try to test the game with one server player and two client players there is a problem:

1. Server to Client: Works normal
2. Client to Server: Works normal
3. Client to Client: Players always facing right

   ```
   using UnityEngine.Networking;

   [SyncVar(hook = "serverTurn")]
   public bool turnState;

   void Update()
   {
       if (!isLocalPlayer)
       {
           return;
       }

       ...

       if (Input.mousePosition.x > (Screen.width / 2))
       {
           turnState = true;
           gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

           Cmd_ChangeDirection(turnState);
           serverTurn(turnState);
       }

       else if (Input.mousePosition.x < (Screen.width / 2))
       {
           turnState = false;
           gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);

           Cmd_ChangeDirection(turnState);
           serverTurn(turnState);
       }
   }

   [Command]
   void Cmd_ChangeDirection(bool var) 
   {
       if (var)
       {
           body2d.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
       }
       else 
       {
           body2d.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
       }
   }

   void serverTurn(bool state)
   {
       if (state)
       {
           body2d.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);          
       }
       else 
       {
           body2d.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
       }
   }
   ```

We're doing something wrong but we don't know what. We've also made the gun the player is holding follow the cursor and that works fine. Rotation syncs without a problem, but scale doesn't, so we want to know how to sync object scale from client to client.

Comment: What kind of networking engine are you using? Do you think it is irrelevant?

Comment: We're using UnityEngine.Networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we fixed the problem. If it's going to be of use to anyone, we needed to use RPC to fix the client to client syncronization.